# How to create an array in Matlab but run a function at the same time?

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop

I'm trying to populate an array with values from a function that I am running. In this function I am changing a variable `z2` in increments of `0.01` from `0` to `0.99`. At the same time I want to populate an array with those values. I've tried a while loop and a for loop. How to write this with only a for loop?

my code:

```
Ys = y(2000);
Mp = ((max(y)-Ys)/Ys)*100;
[max, i] = max(y);
tp = t(i);
z = sqrt(((log(Mp))^2)/((pi*pi)+(log(Mp))^2));


%Given Equations
wd = pi/tp;
wn = wd/(sqrt(1-(z*z)));
ts = 4.6/(z*wn);
tr = 1.8/wn;

%for loop for z from 0 to 0.99
for i = 1:100;
   for z2 = 0:0.01:0.99
      %tr*wn = Fa
      Fa(i) = 2.917*z2^2 - 0.4167*z2 + 1;
      i = i + 1;
      if i >= 100;
          break;
      end
    end
end

find_zeta = interp1(Fa, 1.8);

disp(Fa);
disp(find_zeta);
```

error I am experiencing: I am getting only `1`s in my array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it without a loop, in a 'vectorized' matlab statement

```
z2 = 0:0.01:0.99;
Fa = 2.917*z2.^2 - 0.4167.*z2 + 1;
```

First, compute `z2` values that you need. Next, operating on the vector element by element (**note** `.^` syntax) compute Fa. There is a fundamental difference between `^` and `.^` operators, and you really want to know the difference. In general, you can add a `.` to an operator, which means that it will work on individual scalar elements of your array. [Read about matrix and array operators here](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/arithmeticoperators.html). For example:

```
A = rand(10);
B = rand(10);
% matrix multiplication
C=A*B; 
% element by element multiplication
C=A.*B
```

The complaint you got only means that what you do is inefficient. Since matlab does not know the size of `Fa` beforehand, it needs to reallocate the array every time you append to it. You can still use it, it is just inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Index's in matlab start from 1, not from 0 as they do in other programming languages

The error you are getting is about pre-allocating the array.  Add `Fa = zeros(1,100);` to the start of the script and it will go away.

```
Fa = zeros(1,100);
i = 1;
for z2 = 0:0.01:0.99
   Fa(i) = 2.917*z2^2 - 0.4167*z2 + 1;
   i = i +1;
end
```

The use of 'vectorized' as suggested in another answer is more the way to go though.